# Reading a folder

Tags: c++

I'm using the following code from this [website](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/59943-accessing-directories-in-cc-part-i/) about how to read from a folder to get all the files. I'm then "pushing" them into a string vector. 
My question is, when I read all the files, I get `"."` and `".."` as my first to "files" read from the folder; what are these two "files"?

Furthermore, this code does achieve the goal. I'm just curious as to what these two "files" really are.

I'm using Xcode, and this is in C++.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: The main function for accessing a directory is `readdir`.  There is no `readfolder` function.  The first step in understanding how to use readdir is to stop using the word "folder" when you are talking about a directory.

Answer (score 0):

In linux and unix there is no difference between a file and a directory. Note that in the case of these dot files they are actually not "real files" though, that's another topic.

```
 The "." is a special file in the folder which means "the current directory" and ".." is another special file which means "the parent directory".
```

Comment: Oh that's right, like in Terminal you use: cd .. to go back to the previous directory. I suppose I should say "parent directory". But "previous" is just how I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Directories do not contain files.  Directories contain names.  The names are links to  objects in the filesystem. The names `.` and `..` are links to the directory and its parent, respectively.